# Android Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION works perfect and I can't get the same results with accelerometer and magnetometer

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying to use this non-deprecated version of code to get orientation. However I can't get it to work as smooth and perfect as if I just use the deprecated Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION. Am I missing something?

//OLD

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
    m_lastYaw = arg0.values[0];
    invalidate();
}
```

//NEW

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE){
        return;
    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, m_lastAccels, 0, 3);
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, m_lastMagFields, 0, 3);
    }

    if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(m_rotationMatrix, null, m_lastAccels, m_lastMagFields)) {
        SensorManager.getOrientation(m_rotationMatrix, m_orientation); 

        m_lastYaw = (float)Math.toDegrees(m_orientation[0]);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't dismiss `SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE` values because, on some low-end devices, it's the only values you're gonna get (and these values are actually usable in my tests)

Answer (score 0):

I used the code that I posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299336/2210921) and it worked well only when the phone (Samsung Galaxy S3) layed flat. But it's a start: It doesn't work better than `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` nor worse.