# How do I get the correct bearing (magnetic orientation) regardless of screen orientation?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, bearing, digital-compass

I want to get the current magnetic orientation regardless of the current screen orientation (landscape or portrait).

I found [this](http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html) example, but it's not orientation independant, right? And [this](http://www.touchqode.com/misc/20101025_jsug/20101025_touchqode_sensors.pdf) didn't help me either. I did also read http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html.

This is my current approach with the deprecated way I don't want to use (short):

```
mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        /* Get measured value */
        float current_measured_bearing = (float) event.values[0];

        /* Compensate device orientation */
        switch (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            current_measured_bearing = current_measured_bearing + 90f;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            current_measured_bearing = current_measured_bearing - 180f;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            current_measured_bearing = current_measured_bearing - 90f;
            break;
        }
```

But the last part is definitely wrong! How do I use the newer method `getRotationMatrix()` correctly in this case? (Orientation independent) Or do I simply have to use other values of the `event.values[]` array based on the Rotation Matrix? Or will I need to 'remap the coordinates'? So is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744201/android-sensor-type-orientation-works-perfect-and-i-cant-get-the-same-results-w) the correct way of achieving this?

I'm developing for devices with 360° screen rotation and on API Level 11+.

I know that those questions are asked very often but I could simply not transfer their answers to my question.

Comment: I had the same problem posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772923/how-can-i-get-the-magnetic-field-vector-independent-of-the-device-rotation but the answer didn't work for me. Perhaps you have more luck.

Comment: Do you still need it? Because maybe we 'have to use other values of the event.values[] array?' based on the screen rotation?

Comment: No, I cancelled the project (some AR stuff) as it turned out that the rotation sensors of most Android devices are not exact enough for what I had in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK I finally managed to get the code working!

First, I register a `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` and `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY`: (like Hoan Nguyen said!)

```
/**
 * Initialize the Sensors (Gravity and magnetic field, required as a compass
 * sensor)
 */
private void initSensors() {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor mSensorGravity = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY);
    Sensor mSensorMagneticField = sensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    /* Initialize the gravity sensor */
    if (mSensorGravity != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Gravity sensor available. (TYPE_GRAVITY)");
        sensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener,
                mSensorGravity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Gravity sensor unavailable. (TYPE_GRAVITY)");
    }

    /* Initialize the magnetic field sensor */
    if (mSensorMagneticField != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Magnetic field sensor available. (TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)");
        sensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener,
                mSensorMagneticField, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG,
                "Magnetic field sensor unavailable. (TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)");
    }
}
```

And I use that `SensorEventListner` for the computation:

```
private SensorEventListener mSensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {

            mGravity = event.values.clone();

        } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

            mMagnetic = event.values.clone();

        }

        if (mGravity != null && mMagnetic != null) {

            /* Create rotation Matrix */
            float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
            if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null,
                    mGravity, mMagnetic)) {

                /* Compensate device orientation */
                // http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html
                float[] remappedRotationMatrix = new float[9];
                switch (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                        .getRotation()) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
                            SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Y,
                            remappedRotationMatrix);
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
                            SensorManager.AXIS_Y,
                            SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
                            remappedRotationMatrix);
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
                            SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
                            SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y,
                            remappedRotationMatrix);
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
                            SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y,
                            SensorManager.AXIS_X, remappedRotationMatrix);
                    break;
                }

                /* Calculate Orientation */
                float results[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedRotationMatrix,
                        results);

                /* Get measured value */
                float current_measured_bearing = (float) (results[0] * 180 / Math.PI);
                if (current_measured_bearing < 0) {
                    current_measured_bearing += 360;
                }

                /* Smooth values using a 'Low Pass Filter' */
                current_measured_bearing = current_measured_bearing
                        + SMOOTHING_FACTOR_COMPASS
                        * (current_measured_bearing - compass_last_measured_bearing);

                /* Update normal output */
                visual_compass_value.setText(String.valueOf(Math
                        .round(current_bearing))
                        + getString(R.string.degrees));

                /*
                 * Update variables for next use (Required for Low Pass
                 * Filter)
                 */
                compass_last_measured_bearing = current_measured_bearing;

            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you try to achieve here? Hold your device in portrait mode and then rotate the device by 15 degree the current_measured_bearing will be differed by 15 degree. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes thats It, for example.

Comment: hey what is the value for SMOOTHING_FACTOR_COMPASS??

Comment: Can you add all imports and consts?

Answer (score 4):

`Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` is depreciated and only good if the device is flat. When using `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION`, the bearing (azimuth) is the direction where the device `Y-axis` points. So if the device is held vertical, the direction where the `Y-axis` points using as the bearing does not make sense. It only make sense to calculate the direction where the back camera points. To find this direction you have to use `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` and `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY` or `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`. If using `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`, you have to filter the accelerometer values.
Using these sensors, you call `getRotationMatrix` and then `remapCoordinateSystem(inR, AXIS_X, AXIS_Z, outR)` before calling `getOrientation`. To get a stable direction you should keep a history of the direction and then calculate the average. For an implementation using TYPE_GRAVITY check [Android getOrientation Azimuth gets polluted when phone is tilted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979238/android-getorientation-azimuth-gets-polluted-when-phone-is-tilted/17981374#17981374)

Comment: Thank you for this solution. So now I'm going to write the code based on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code may help you:

```
    //get orientation
private int getScreenOrientation() {
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int orientation;
    // if the device's natural orientation is portrait:
    if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) && height > width ||
        (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) && width > height) {
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " +
                        "portrait.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;              
        }
    }
    // if the device's natural orientation is landscape or if the device
    // is square:
    else {
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " +
                        "landscape.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;              
        }
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

Comment: Thamk you for your code and sorry for such a late answer, but this only returnes the screen orientation as an int (in the `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_XX`-style). This is a very useful part of code, but do you also know how to use the rotation matrix?

Comment: Can you help me out on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997669/android-acceleration-down-smash) please?